# Why is syn conformer of methyl formate more stable than trans conformer

Tags: organic-chemistry

As stated, I've read this in a textbook and it seems not explainable solely based on steric clash or Coulombic interactions. I know for such a simple molecule, it can be predicted ab initio using quantum mechanical models ([A paper on this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/244280731_Molecular_conformations_of_methyl_formate_and_methyl_vinyl_ether_from_ab_initio_molecular_orbital_calculations)), yet, I'm seeking a simple explanation for this conformer preference. Would anybody kindly explain to me the logic behind this? Thanks.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20185/why-are-lactones-more-acidic-than-esters

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59458/which-electronic-effects-are-responsible-for-the-reduction-of-nucleophilicity-of